# How to disable cookies on my weebly website?

Tags: cookie, eu-cookie-law, weebly

I have a website built with Weebly. It is just a simple static webpage. It seems to me that this kind of site doesn't require any kind of cookie, since there is no user log-in, no preference to be set, etc.

Unfortunately, Weebly sets up by default a few cookies, that are in my case unnecessary, they are described [here](https://www.weebly.com/app/help/us/en/topics/add-a-cookie-banner-to-your-website). Having cookies requires me to set up a cookie banner to comply with GDPR and other laws, which I would avoid if I can.

Is it possible to disable all cookies from my website?

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in the weebly code a setcookie or javascript cookie is written. If you can delete that part then no cookie will be set anymore. You could add a code to overwrite these cookies but that would be a weird solution.

BTW, I dont know weebly. But the cookie banner you try to avoid is not because your website sets a cookie. The laws are about someone will use the site visitors personal data as IP or duration of a visit or entered perosnal data. if weebly does this, you need a "accept" banner anyway so the users accepts BEFORE any personal data is stored. But back to the topic. To prevent setcookie u need to delete that part from your code of your website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to you that its a static site and it is not using cookies, but you are using weebly and readymade themes/templates available there. You need to make sure that any and all Javascript used even on a static page does not set cookies. Another thing is that cookies banner is not just about cookies but it is also about data collection and privacy. Who knows if weebly itself is collecting that data on their end.